# How to enable hardware acceleration depending on a device

Tags: java, android, cordova, hardware-acceleration

I am getting this error:

```
E/libEGL(11261): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

I found out that a possible solution would be to use

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

But the issue is that I want to run the app on android 2.2 up.

If I add that setting to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, it won't compile because it will give an error.

Is there a way to enable that option based on device version, or maybe use a different solution?

I am using phonegap.

edit:

found the solution, i didn't had the deviceready listener running

Comment: android:hardwareAccelerated is a feature in 2.3.3 or above, so it won't compile. Did you create any new Surfaceview extends from GLSurfaceView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this .

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    (your view)view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Comment: its your main layout view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to call window's method:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

Actually, the method is available in 2.2, but constants values are not. You can hard-code them or use the reflection.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html for more details on per-view hardware acceleration control.

Comment: In the onCreate() method of your activity, before setContentView().

Comment: the method only contains
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }`

Comment: and `FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` fails. do you have a more complete example with the dependencies?

Comment: Oh, you are using PhoneGap... I've realized that this is actually android's WebView bug ( some conversation on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8825054/1761411 ). The setContentView() is called inside PhoneGap's code ( super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in your code ). You can try to set window flags right in the first line, but I don't know if android accepts this.